# Chapter name separate from chapter titles in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, report, titletoc

I want my chapter title names to be on separate line dotted as shown in the picture below [image] observe that the chapter name is in Arabic dotted on its own line and the name of the chapter follows. I have tried the following

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}
   [0pt]% <left>
   {\bfseries}% <above-code>
   {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel:\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
   {}% <numberless-entry-format>
   {\titlerule*[0.8pc]{.}\contentspage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\author{Your Name}
\title{The Tittle of the document  Goes Here}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
 \section{First Section}
 \lipsum[1-1]
 \section{Second Section}
 \lipsum[1-1]
 \section{Third Section}
 \lipsum[1-1]
 \chapter{Introduction}
 \section{First Section}
 \lipsum[1-1]
 \section{Second Section}
 \lipsum[1-1]
 \section{Third Section}
 \lipsum[1-1]
 \end{document}
```

This code prints the following

[image]

Note that headings are not in Arabic as shown in the first imagine above as they contain numeric that is chapter 1. Also, the chapter names are printing on the same line as the chapter titles which I do not want. I do not know how I can get what I want. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Numberstring{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}
   [0pt]% <left>
   {\medskip\bfseries}% <above-code>
   {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\hspace{0.3em}\titlerule*[0.8pc]{.}\contentspage\endgraf}% <numbered-entry-format>
   {}% <numberless-entry-format>
   {\titlerule*[0.8pc]{.}\contentspage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\author{Your Name}
\title{The Title of the document Goes Here}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
 \section{First Section}
 \lipsum[1-1]
 \section{Second Section}
 \lipsum[1-1]
 \section{Third Section}
 \lipsum[1-1]
 \chapter{Introduction}
 \section{First Section}
 \lipsum[1-1]
 \section{Second Section}
 \lipsum[1-1]
 \section{Third Section}
 \lipsum[1-1]

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is close to what I want but can you make chapters print as Chapter One etc instead of chapter 1?

Comment: @MafeniAlpha: Do you also want to have it this way in the chapter headings, not only in the table of contents?

Comment: @MafeniAlpha: I've updated  my code. Please see if it suits you. Of cource the chapter heading will also be modified.